# Is it possible to set CFLAGS to a linux kernel module Makefile?

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Eg: a common device module's Makefile

```
obj-m:=jc.o

default:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(shell pwd) modules
clean:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(shell pwd) modules clean
```

I consider if I can set CFLAGS to the file. When I change *default* section to

```
$(MAKE) -O2 -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(shell pwd) modules
```

But it didn't work.

Any help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `$$PWD` can replace `$(shell pwd)`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`-O2` would be an option to `make` (or `$(MAKE)`, as you're using it) in what you tried. Obviously, the compiler (probably `gcc`) needs this flag, not `make`.

Kbuild understands a make variable named `CFLAGS_modulename.o` to add specific C flags when compiling this unit. In your case, your module object will be `jc.o`, so you can specify:

```
CFLAGS_jc.o := -O2
```

and it should work. Add `V=1` to your `$(MAKE)` lines to get a verbose output and you should see `-O2` when `jc.c` is being compiled.

You can find more about compiling modules in [the official documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt).

Answer (score 19):

You can also use

```
ccflags-y := -O2
```

This will be applied to all of the source files compiled for your module with the Makefile.  This is indirectly documented in the link provided by eepp in [Section 4.2](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.13/source/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt#L328)

Comment: This will override `ccflags-y` setting in some inner `Makefile`s, and as a result will break `.h` file lookup.

Comment: For me, it helped to use `EXTRA_CFLAGS` instead. It is referenced in `scripts/Makefile.lib` as a thing for "backwards compatibility" and it is *added* to `ccflags-y`, thus not breaking anything.

Comment: `ccflags-y += -O2` should work.  It was shown in `Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this by buildroot configuration instead of needing to modify Makefiles?