# kbuild external module questions

Tags: c, linux, makefile, kbuild

I am building an out-of-tree kernel module for a device driver. Overall, things are going well, but I had a few questions about using kbuild and the build system:

1. I found this excellent post: [Is it possible to set CFLAGS to a linux kernel module Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478859/is-it-possible-to-set-cflags-to-a-linux-kernel-module-makefile), which shows how to modify the compiler flags. As a result, I am now setting my compiler flags as: `ccflags-y := -O2 -Wall -Wextra -I $(DRIVER_INC_DIR)`, where `$(DRIVER_INC_DIR)` is various header files for my driver. Note that my driver is made up of several .o files that get merged into a single .ko.  I want to show warnings generated by the compiler for my own code, but not code in Linux (e.g., linux/module.h). How can I accomplish that? I know in user space applications there is the `-isystem` option, but I'm wondering how that would apply here (if at all).
2. Is there any difference between using `modules_install` versus just doing a copy of the .ko file after it has been compiled? The reason I ask is because I think its easier for me to follow doing a manual copy, since I also need to support a "make uninstall" target (and there is no `modules_uninstall`, just a `clean`, which does not appear to remove the .ko from where it was installed).

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to answer #1. Basically, inside of kbuild, the `LINUXINCLUDE` variable is using `-I` to pull in all the source code from the Linux headers.  As a result, I added this line to my Makefile:

```
LINUXINCLUDE := $(subst -I, -isystem, $(LINUXINCLUDE))
```

This replaces all the `-I` flags with `-isystem` and therefore, the warnings are ignored.