# Predefine a macro in kernel module

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel, macros, kernel-module

I would like to define a macro for my kernel module by using the `-D` flag, but I can't figure out how to do it in a custom loadable kernel module.

Just to be clear, to set the macro TEST to 1 I usually do something like: 
`cc -D TEST=1 file.c -o file`

And inside the file.c I have

```
#if TEST
   //do something
#endif
```

Now, having the same code in a kernel module, how can I set TEST to 1 without touching the code?

This is my the Makefile:

```
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD)  modules
```

Since the `-C` flag it's recursively calling multiple makefiles, adding `-D TEST=1` does not work, I get the following error:
`make: invalid option -- 'D'`

Anybody knows how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `make CFLAGS=-DTEST`.

Comment: @n.m. I get `warning: "TEST" is not defined [-Wundef]` 
I need not only to define it, but also give it a value, like TEST=2, etc...

Comment: You can do this too of course `CFLAGS=-DTEST=2`, and just `-DTEST` is equivalent to `-DTEST=1`. But `CFLAGS` is incorrect for compiling a kernel module, you need to use `make EXTRA_CFLAGS=...` instead. Mea maxima culpa.

Comment: You made my day! It works now. I will post your solution as answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to set CFLAGS to a linux kernel module Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478859/is-it-possible-to-set-cflags-to-a-linux-kernel-module-makefile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @n.m. in the comments, the solution is to use the `EXTRA_CFLAGS`. 
So in my case it would be something like this:

```
all:
make EXTRA_CFLAGS=-DTEST=2 -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

or simply

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS:= -D TEST=2

all:
     make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD)  modules
```