# How specify optimization level of compilation for kernel module

Tags: c, makefile, linux-kernel

I am writing a simple makefile for loadable kernel module, in below you can see makefile content:

```
obj-m += ali.o
all:
   make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
   make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

this make file work, but i do't know how specify optimization level of compilation in this makefile.

can anyone help to set the optimization level of compilation??

Comment: Optimization level of what? a gcc compilation?

Comment: yes, optimization of compilation.

Comment: That question is for the free-bsd kernel

Comment: are you using Kbuild?

Comment: @RedaDrissi no, that is my makefile and i just use make command to build the module.

Comment: you should be able to set some variables, but I don't know exactly which, try `EXTRA_CFLAGS := -O2` or `ccflags-y := -O2` or `CFLAGS_ali.o := -O2`. 
Also add `V=1` to your make commands to activate verbose mode and see whether the flags were included while ali.c was compiled.

Comment: Optimization level for specific modules or the whole compilation?

Comment: The kernel Makefiles will already apply the `-O2` or `-Os` option. If you add competing `-O` options in the module's Makefile, I'm not sure which one will take precedence.

Comment: This, I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478859/is-it-possible-to-set-cflags-to-a-linux-kernel-module-makefile